# Bigquery Backend Error when exporting results to a table

Tags: google-bigquery

There is some time that the query runs perfectly, but lately has appeared to me this error: "Backend Error".
I know that my query is huge, and it takes about 300 seconds to execute. But I imagine this is some BigQuery's bug, so I wonder why this error is happening.

This error started appears when I was executing some other queries, when I just wanted the results and not export them.

So I started to create a table with the results hopping that BigQuery could be able to perform the query

Here is an image that shows the error:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I looked up your job in the BigQuery job database, and it completed successfully after 160 seconds.

BigQuery queries are fundamentally asynchronous. That is, when you run a query, it runs as a named Job by the BigQuery service. Since the original call may timeout, usual best-practice is to poll for completion by using the jobs.getQueryResults() API. My guess is that this is the API call that actually failed.

We had reports of an elevated number of Backend Errors yesterday and we're still investigating. However, these don't appear to be actual failed queries, instead they are failures getting the status of queries or getting the results, that should go away by retrying.

How did you run the query? Did you use the BigQuery Web UI? If you are using the API, did you call the bigquery.jobs.insert() api or the bigquery.jobs.query() api?

Comment: I've used BigQuery Web UI.

Comment: After some time retrying, I finally receive a result.